# Need someone to test the below command to check disk space on Clearcase -stgloc

Tags: clearcase

The following command is **non-destructive** and is intended to query space left on view storage device. It will be really helpful if u tell me this works fine at your end too. I wish to create a generalized version of this command which tells me space left on the disk of the viewstg on which the view was created.

1 ) Set a view

2) Execute the below command which will give you spaceLeft on device.

```
ct pwv|grep "Set view:"|cut -d: -f2|xargs /usr/atria/bin/cleartool lsview|rev | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | rev|xargs df -h|awk '{print $3}'|grep G
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can work, but you can get the name of the current view without having to use `grep` and `cut`.

```
ct lsview -cview
```

By default, it prints:

- The view tag (if you are in a view)
- The view-storage directory path name

  ```
  ct lsview -cview |rev | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | rev|xargs df -h|awk '{print $3}'|grep G
  ```

---

Another way would have been to check the output of [`cleartool space`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_space.htm), but since your way works, it seems more complex to try this other command.

Comment: Thanks a lot you rock \m/ VonC when it comes to clearcase related issues :)